# Retrieve rows by specific value of the cell in Excel

Tags: excel

```
PNR   |  No.of Pax  |  Client   
GHTRF        1         ABC Travels
JUYTH        4         XYZ Travels
RFEDS        1         ZZZ Travels
HTGGU        3         ABC Travels
```

This is my main Excel Sheet and I need to get the rows by specific client on a new sheet to make separate statement for my clients.

that is, I need to generate statement for ***ABC Travels*** as below.

```
  PNR  |  No.of Pax  |  Client    
GHTRF         1         ABC Travels
HTGGU         3         ABC Travels
```

is there any functions in Excel to do this?

Comment: Look into advanced filter.

Comment: @ScottCraner , Its working but it isn't work automatically  when I trying to make for another client by changing the criteria cell value. It need to do all stemps again.

Comment: Then you will need vba, to automate  see [HERE](http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/).  This will give you a good starting point on using advanced filter in vba.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a way to locate all the good rows *(ABC rows)*.  In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(LEFT(C2,3)="ABC",1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

now it is a simple *INDEX()* and *MATCH()*.  In **E2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),$D:$D,0)),"")
```

copy this both across and down:
[image]

Comment: I need to make it in new Sheet

Comment: @ShihabEK  Leave the column the **D** material in the data sheet and move the columns **E, F, G** material to the new sheet.

Comment: i'm trying to to all this automaticaly, otherwise I can add a simple filter to client column and copy to another sheet, right?

Comment: I think its better to move to SQL and PHP